ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it even when the trigger is not updating the table on which it is written
I have a trigger as below
create or replace TRIGGER trg_**
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SPEC_DDS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- First, set sdd_enabled to 'no' for all rows in SPEC_DP
  UPDATE SPEC_DP
  SET sdd_enabled = 'no';

  -- Next, set sdd_enabled to 'yes' for specific rows
  UPDATE SPEC_DP
  SET sdd_enabled = 'yes'
  WHERE spec_id IN (
    SELECT spec_id
    FROM ERPM_SPECS
    WHERE artifact_id IN (
      SELECT TO_NUMBER(data_slice_id)
      FROM SPEC_DDS
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$')
    )
  );
END;
/

I am getting error
ORA-04091: table WKSP_ERPM.SPEC_DM_DATA_SLICES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

I am not updating the table on which the trigger is given. So what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

True, you aren't updating that table, but you're selecting from it, here:
SELECT TO_NUMBER(data_slice_id)
FROM SPEC_DDS                                --> that's the table 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$')

and that causes the error. Oracle won't let you select from a table that's just being modified.

Although you can get out of the mutating table error (using a package or a compound trigger or converting this one into an autonomous transaction (not the best idea, though)), do you really need a trigger? Why wouldn't you convert this code into a procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_enabled
IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE spec_dp
      SET sdd_enabled = 'no';

   -- Next, set sdd_enabled to 'yes' for specific rows
   UPDATE spec_dp
      SET sdd_enabled = 'yes'
    WHERE spec_id IN
             (SELECT spec_id
                FROM erpm_specs
               WHERE artifact_id IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER (data_slice_id)
                                       FROM spec_dds
                                      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$')));
END;

and call it after performing DML on SPEC_DDS table. For example,
begin
  -- do something here

  -- update SPEC_DDS
  update spec_dds set ...

  -- call the procedure
  p_enabled;

  -- do some more stuff

end;


You are selecting from a table you are updating. This is forbidden, because depending on in which order the DBMS processes the rows in the update, the query might get different results. In other words: the query would not be deterministic.
Your mistake is that you have written an after-each-row trigger (AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SPEC_DDS FOR EACH ROW), when you actually want an after-statement trigger. This is done by simply omitting the FOR EACH ROW clause:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_**
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON spec_dds
BEGIN
  -- First, set sdd_enabled to 'no' for all rows in SPEC_DP
  UPDATE spec_dp
  SET sdd_enabled = 'no';

  -- Next, set sdd_enabled to 'yes' for specific rows
  UPDATE spec_dp
  SET sdd_enabled = 'yes'
  WHERE spec_id IN (
    SELECT spec_id
    FROM erpm_specs
    WHERE artifact_id IN (
      SELECT TO_NUMBER(data_slice_id)
      FROM spec_dds
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$')
    )
  );
END;
/

If sdd_enabled shall only depend on spec_dds/erpm_specs data, then I wouldn't store this in a column and fill it with a trigger, but create a view for this instead.

rewrote the trigger in this way
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_***
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SPEC_DDS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Set sdd_enabled to 'no' for all rows in SPEC_DP
  UPDATE SPEC_DP
  SET sdd_enabled = 'no';

  -- Handle INSERT and UPDATE scenarios
  IF INSERTING THEN
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(:NEW.data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$') THEN
      UPDATE SPEC_DP p
      SET p.sdd_enabled = 'yes'
      WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ERPM_SPECS s
        WHERE s.artifact_id = TO_NUMBER(:NEW.data_slice_id)
          AND s.spec_id = p.spec_id
      );
    END IF;

  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    -- Only proceed if data_slice_id is actually updated
    IF :NEW.data_slice_id != :OLD.data_slice_id AND REGEXP_LIKE(:NEW.data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$') THEN
      UPDATE SPEC_DP p
      SET p.sdd_enabled = 'yes'
      WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ERPM_SPECS s
        WHERE s.artifact_id = TO_NUMBER(:NEW.data_slice_id)
          AND s.spec_id = p.spec_id
      );
    END IF;
  END IF;

END;
/


That code doesn't do what the original does. The original fetches all ERPM_SPECS rows whose ARTIFACT_ID matches SPEC_DDS.DATA_SLICE_ID throughout the whole SPEC_DDS table. Code you posted here does that only for the newly modified DATA_SLICE_ID.

Don't do it for each row, do it after the statement has completed:
create or replace TRIGGER trg_**
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SPEC_DDS
BEGIN
  UPDATE SPEC_DP
  SET sdd_enabled = CASE WHEN spec_id IN (
    SELECT spec_id
    FROM ERPM_SPECS
    WHERE artifact_id IN (
      SELECT TO_NUMBER(data_slice_id)
      FROM SPEC_DDS
      WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(data_slice_id, '^[0-9]+$')
    )
  ) then 'yes' else 'no' end;
END;
/

I also merged your two updates into a single one.
The problem is that if you specify for each row, then the result is undeterministic, or at least it can be undeterministic theoretically.
